# Css working fine for development but not being applied after production buid - React

Tags: css, reactjs

I created an app using `create-react-app`, while running the code for development using `npm start` the pages are loading fine with all the css but when I build the project using `npm run build` the css won't load. Below are the attached screenshots and code snippets.

Page being loaded in development.

[image]

Same page when the build folder is served.

[image]

Here is the App.js imports

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "jquery/dist/jquery.min.js";
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js";
import "./assets/css/classy-nav.min.css";
import "./assets/vendors/font-awesome/v5.9.0/all.css";
import "./assets/vendors/animate-css/animate.css";
import "./assets/vendors/magnify-popup/magnific-popup.css";
import "./assets/css/style.css";
import "owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css";
import "owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.css";
import { toast, ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import $ from "jquery";
import { WOW } from "wowjs";
toast.configure();
```

Comment: where have you imported your css file ?

Comment: In my App.js file

Comment: can you share your App.js code

Comment: @HritikSharma the APP.js other than this has just the page imports and the routes for those pages.

Answer (score 0):

You might just need to run `npm start` after `npm install`.

Comment: That will start a local server for development, I am facing issue while creating the production build.

Answer (score 0):

Got same issue, solved it with injecting styling on demand: https://fkhadra.github.io/react-toastify/how-to-style#inject-style-on-demand (instead of *import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";*)

```
import { injectStyle } from "react-toastify/dist/inject-style";

// CALL IT ONCE IN YOUR APP
injectStyle();
```